# nomedia file in cache folders (Android)

Tags: java, android, multimedia

I'm trying to create a .nomedia file into cache folder with following code

```
private static final String NOMEDIA_FILE = ".nomedia";
    path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/data/"+cnt.getApplicationInfo().packageName+"/cache/");
    path.mkdirs();

    file= new File(path,NOMEDIA_FILE);
    if (!file.exists()){
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`file.createNewFile()` returns true, later `file.exists()` return `true`, but the file dont appears at the folder. If I use another path the snipplet works. Are the cache folders automatically ignored in media scan? If not, how can I make the .nomedia file in there?

Thanks

Comment: Your path is `/sdcard/Android/data/<Packagename>/cache/`. Are you sure about that? Also **fails** is a bad error description.

Answer (score 0):

The file does exist but is hidden in default directory lists; that's what the prefixed period (.) does.

Confirm from the command line by starting an *adb shell* and using *ls -a* to show all files. It would look something like this:

```
C:\Users>adb shell
root@android:/ # cd /sdcard/learnpad
root@android:/sdcard/learnpad # ls -a
.nomedia
data.learnpad.co
profile.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The file does exist.

It is your file explorer's settings that determine if you can see a hidden folder or not.

Just open your file explorer, go to settings, and turn on "show hidden folders"